# how do I reinstall a .deb package without the file in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, deb, rosegarden

I have rosegarden installed via *.deb and I need to reinstall it.
how do I do that in 12.04?
Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Rosegarden is in the 12.04 repository.  Open Software center, type 'rosegarden' into the search box, then install it (or re-install).

Press <kbd>super</kbd> then type 'software center' in the search bar, then click on the icon to open software center.

Comment: via software centre?

Comment: I've added instructions to open the software center.  You've never used it?  Boy are you in for a treat...